# TYPO3 v8LTS form framework form definition storage

Tags: typo3, yaml, typoscript, tsconfig, typo3-8.x

I run half a dozen different TYPO3-installations all based on the same sitepackage with a few dozen to a few hundred websites in each installation. Content between websites in individual installations needs to be separated. [In order to achieve that form wise I can now add as many allowedFileMounts to the form configuration yaml as I need](https://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/extensions/form/8.7/Concepts/FormFileStorages/Index.html). The editors will only gain access to those allowedFileMounts that they have a filemount for defined on their backenduser or backendusergroup, making sure that no editor meddles with other website editors forms. To give all groups of editors access to their individual forms definition folder would require to have hundreds of allowedFileMounts defined in the sitepackage, or, as filepaths may be ambigious between installations, to have a separate yaml file in each TYPO3-installation.

With every new website setup in one of the aforementioned TYPO3-installations the corresponding yaml file would have to be adjusted as well. I wonder if there's a more elegant or rather: simple way to achieve that? For example defining the allowedFileMounts for forms definitions in a backendusergroup itself via TSconfig?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The function getAccessibleFormStorageFolders inside FormPersistenceManager has no other magic than just reading the allowedFileMounts from the  formSettings.
But maybe you can XCLASS this function and create your own logic based on the logged in user?

Class \TYPO3\CMS\Form\Mvc\Persistence\FormPersistenceManager

Comment: Cheers and sorry for the lack of a reply. We eventually did exactly what you suggested.